# How to have a maximum waiting time for getchar in C

Tags: c

I am writing a project with C, using CodeBlocks in Windows, in which I am showing some moving characters in the console (I don't want to use the graphics features). For that, I print the characters and wait a little bit and then use system(cls) and shift the location of characters, and print the characters again, so it looks like moving.

What I want to add is this: in case the user hits the upper key, the characters move upward, otherwise they continue the way they were moving. I tried to use getchar(), but the problem is that it waits to make sure a character is hit, without any timeout. So in case nothing is hit, the program stops showing the moving characters. Is there a way to add a timeout feature to getchar or use a different method?

Comment: Im not sure but I think you should redirect the `STDIN` to a file and try to read that file.

Comment: Take a look at `select`. You can provide a timeout for input, but you will probably need to place the keyboard in raw, unbuffered mode.

Comment: You probably want to use some non-standard console API for this. Pure standard C is too crude.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Is it true that `select` doesn't work very well on windows?

Comment: Dear all, thanks for your comments. I edited my question to clarify that I am using CodeBlocks in windows.
@Lundin: Could you please clarify more, or give a hint, example,..

Comment: Manual here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682010(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

There is no portable way to do this.

On Posix compliant systems, you can use `select()` with a timeout to check if input is available from the system handle 0, the process standard input. You can then use `read` to get the pending input.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, you can use the old `<conio.h>` functions:

- [`_kbhit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c.aspx) which tell you if the keyboard has been pressed,
- [`_getch()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx) which will get the key value.

But using these functions is not really portable. You could use something like [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) to do what you want. For Windows, a good library exists: [PDCurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

You may try using setvbuf to associate a buffer with stdin then look at contents of buffer to check if user entered anything rather than calling getch